# How to download file in new tab on button click in mvc 4

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4

I have written code to view the file from remote server. I am able to view when the button is clicked. Actually I want to open a file in new tab when I click on button. This is what I tried so far.

```
 public ActionResult Download(string filepath, string filename)
        {
            service.Service objService = new service.Service();
            byte[] result = objService.DownloadFileFromDMS(filepath);
            System.IO.FileStream fs1 = null;
            string contentType = MimeMapping.GetMimeMapping(filepath);

            var cd = new System.Net.Mime.ContentDisposition
            {
                FileName = filename,
                Inline = true,
            };
            Response.AppendHeader("Content-Disposition",  cd.ToString());
            return File(result, contentType);
        }
```

Everything fine here but file will open up in the same tab. I want to open it in new tab. Is there any thing missing in current code? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you invoke your Download controller from View do it as,

```
@Html.ActionLink("DownloadFile", "Download", "MyController", new { filepath = item.FilePath.ToString(), filename = item.FileName.ToString() }, new { @target = "_blank" })
```

Trick here is we create a `<a>` tag with target attribute set to _blank. 
This will download the file in a new tab.

I just assumed this happens when iterating your file item collection and added "item.FilePath.ToString()" and "item.FileName.ToString()" attributes.

It's always a good idea to use Async in these types of controllers as it waits for external call.

Answer (score 0):

try using something similar to below?

```
Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(
    this.GetType(), File(result, contentType), script, true
);
```

Major problem is most clients will block it as a pop-up. better to load in the current tab, either via a modal or inner window.

The biggest issue with you're approach is that you cant control client functionality from the server, so you will have to use a client based script to perform the action.

Comment: Yes I understood. So the way I have used is not efficient one?